# How do I save a member?

Tags: java

I am doing a project in college which we are to create a java program to add golfers to a list of members.  I am having trouble getting them added to the list!

This is my code so far:

```
*import java.util.*;
public class GolfClubTester {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
            System.out.println("Please enter number for:");
            System.out.println("1: Joining Member:");
            System.out.println("2: Remove an old Member:");
            System.out.println("3: Search for a Member:");
            System.out.println("4: View all");
            //Ask User for input
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i = input.nextInt();

                if(i == 1){
                    //Clear scanner input buffer
                    input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter Members name:");
                    String name = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter day:");
                    int day = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter month");
                    int month = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter year:");
                    int year = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter Handicap:");
                    int Handicap = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter Id:");
                    int MemId = input.nextInt();

                    //Clear scanner input buffer
                    input.nextLine();
                    //Ask user type of Member
                    System.out.println("Please enter type of Member:");
                    System.out.println("1 - Senior:");
                    System.out.println("2 - Junior:");
                    int i1 = input.nextInt();
                        if (i1 == 1){
                           //Create member object
                           Date join1 = new Date(day,month,year);
                           SeniorMembers s1 = new SeniorMembers(name,join1,Handicap,MemId);
                           //Display member details
                           System.out.println("**Senior Member has joined**");
                           System.out.println(s1);
                           return;
                       }
                        else if (i1 == 2){
                            Date join1 = new Date(day,month,year);
                            JuniorMembers j1 = new JuniorMembers(name,join1,Handicap,MemId);
                            //Display member details
                            System.out.println("**Junior Member has joined**");
                            System.out.println(j1);
                        }
                        else{
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input:");

                     }
                }*
```

So I can get it to say the member has joined but it doesn't actually save the member. Can anyone help and tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Sounds like you should have a list or array of members somewhere and add each new member to that list.

Comment: Create a `List`, first.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how I can do this? Sorry very weak at this

Comment: **Improvement** You should create a Member object instead of JuniorMember and SeniorMember, then create for member a variable that tells you what kind of member it is--> public boolean isSenior(){  if(memberType == 1)  {  return true;  }else{  return false;  }

Comment: @marcosE. If you are going to use `memberType` to separate juniors and seniors, use an `enum`, not an `int`. That being said, I'm not sure that is an improvement. There may be a valid reason for modelling `SeniorMember` and `JuniorMembor` in separate classes.

Comment: The class names `JuniorMembers` and `SeniorMembers` should not be plural.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<SeniorMember> seniorMembersList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<JuniorMember> juniorMembersList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Please enter number for:");
        System.out.println("1: Joining Member:");

        .......

                   if (i1 == 1){
                       //Create member object
                       Date join1 = new Date(day,month,year);
                       SeniorMembers s1 = new SeniorMembers(name,join1,Handicap,MemId);
                       //
                       //Adding here
                       //
                       seniorMembersList.add(s1);
                       //Display member details
                       System.out.println("**Senior Member has joined**");
                       System.out.println(s1);
                       return;
                   }
                    else if (i1 == 2){
                        Date join1 = new Date(day,month,year);
                        JuniorMembers j1 = new JuniorMembers(name,join1,Handicap,MemId);
                       //
                       //Adding here
                       //
                        juniorMembersList.add(j1);
                        //Display member details
                        System.out.println("**Junior Member has joined**");
                        System.out.println(j1);
                    }
```

Then you can access these member objects where you need it using seniorMembersList.get(position);

Comment: It's a main method... So you should rather not forget to instanciate the object!

Comment: Use the interface, not the implementation: `List<JuniorMember> juniorMembersList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Dont try to make him learn abstraction, hes learning array management he wont get why, if thats for me dont worry i usually use List<> ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think you'll get it from all the comments and answer, you can store your instances in Lists (for example as `ArrayList<String>`).

As your program is in a `main` method, the lists should be instantiate in this method.

Hint: when you'll go further in your implementation, use a more object oriented approach.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies I think I have enough to make it work!

Comment: Actually if you look at my code theres a 2, 3 and 4, options in which the user can choose and I might be taking this a bit far but I think my code is also wrong for them! What tips do you have for creating the code for those parts? if thats not too much to ask?

Comment: @Greatham29, consider to implements the `equals` function of your classes  `SeniorMember` and `JuniorMember` so that the objects are manageable in the lists. (By the way, you can also use only one list for all members). Then you could have a look to  1>add, 2>remove, 3>contains, 4>toString.